# how to draw nvd3 simple barchart with x and y axis in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

I am using `nvd3.js` plugin in my `angular-js` application. I came up with a simple `bar chart` requirement, where i need to show bars on the `x-axis` that indicates `months`, based on the values on `y-axis` that indicates revenue. I have to achieve this using `nvd3.js plugin`. Can anyone help on how to achieve this using `nvd3.js plugin?`

Answer (score 2):

For your purpose you can try [angular-nvd3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/) directive.

You should just set up chart `options` and chart `data` as json, something like

```
//html
<nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>

//javascript, controller
$scope.options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'discreteBarChart',
        height: 450,
        x: function(d){return d.label;},
        y: function(d){return d.value;},
        showValues: true,
        valueFormat: function(d){
            return d3.format(',.2f')(d);
        },
        transitionDuration: 500,
        xAxis: {
            axisLabel: 'Month',
            rotateLabels: -20
        },
        yAxis: {
            axisLabel: 'Revenue',
            axisLabelDistance: 30
        }
    }
}

$scope.data = [{
    values: [{
        "label" : "Jan" ,
        "value" : 29.765957771107
    },{
        "label" : "Feb" ,
        "value" : 20
    },{
    ...
    }]
}]
```

See [live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/OiNzEy?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have found a way to generate charts using d3.js